# Show specific wifi network after scan on the android native wifi icon?

Tags: android

I am creating an application in android where I have to show specific wifi network after scan on the android native wifi icon.

Specific network to show inside an app is possible but how to **show it on the native android wifi icon** [**List of specific wifi networks**]?

Thanks.

Comment: Did not understand your requirement, could you please brief or share screenshot reference?

Comment: When you go to setting and turn on your wifi it shows you the list of available network on that scan I wanna show only my network[ ANP] rest has to be hide.